# Increase session time of Magento 2 admin panel

Tags: magento-2.1, session, admin-panel

How to increase admin panel's session time ?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCIoE.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To increase session to time for Admin , you need to go :

**Stores** -> **Configuration** -> **Advanced** -> **Admin** -> **Security** -> Admin Session Lifetime (**it must be in seconds**).

**Uncheckd** use System value option and add your value in textbox.

Minimumm second is **60** and Maximum is **31536000** (**for one year**).

**Refer below screenshot for more details.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check it in

```
Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > Admin Session Lifetime (seconds)
```

or execute query in MySQL

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data(path, value) VALUES('admin/security/session_lifetime', 86400);
```